# Fatal error encountered when executing command

Tags: mysql, vb.net, command, visual-studio-2015, fatal-error

I cant seem to find this error stated every time I read from the database. The error shows, but my program still run normally which is weird. I have tried using break points but the error pop out before the form load event. Here is my code.

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick
    fileID = 0
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As New DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        fileID = row.Cells("ID").Value.ToString
        KUP_DATABASE_REPORT.ShowDialog() 'Error pop out on this line
    End If
End Sub
```

The code above is from the main form. When I click on the cell, a new form will show all its data from database. And the code below is the second form where it pulls data from and fill the empty textboxes, etc.
By using breakpoint, the fatal error occurred on the line `KUP_DATABASE_REPORT.ShowDialog()`

```vb
Private Sub KUP_DATABASE_REPORT_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now()
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dddd dd MMMM yyyy"
    NumericUpDown1.ResetText()
    NumericUpDown2.ResetText()
    LoadFileDataFromRead()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadFileDataFromRead()
    Try
        Connect2Database()
        theID = New Integer = 0
        theID = KUP_DATABASE_READ.fileID
        myCommand.CommandText = "Select * from kup_table Where ID = @theIDD"
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theIDD", theID)
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read
            '======================FILE INFO=============================
            NumericUpDown1.Controls.Item(1).Text = reader.GetInt32("FILE_NO")
            NumericUpDown2.Controls.Item(1).Text = reader.GetInt32("FILE_YEAR")
            TextBox1.Text = reader.GetString("FILE_TYPE")
            TextBox2.Text = reader.GetString("FILE_COLOR")
            TextBox3.Text = reader.GetString("FILE_DESC")
            '======================LOT INFO==============================
            ComboBox1.Text = reader.GetString("DAERAH")
            ComboBox2.Text = reader.GetString("MUKIM")
            ComboBox3.Text = reader.GetString("SEKSYEN")
            TextBox4.Text = reader.GetString("LOT")
            ComboBox4.Text = reader.GetString("LOT_INFO")
            TextBox5.Text = reader.GetString("TITLE_NO")
            '======================CLIENT INFO===========================
            TextBox6.Text = reader.GetString("NAME")
            TextBox7.Text = reader.GetString("ADDR")
            TextBox8.Text = reader.GetString("ADDR2")
            TextBox9.Text = reader.GetString("TEL_NUM")
            TextBox10.Text = reader.GetString("FAX_NUM")
            '======================STATUS================================
            RichTextBox1.Text = reader.GetString("STATUS")
            '======================LEVEL/PROCESS=========================
            If reader.GetInt32("TECH_DEPT") = 0 Then
                CheckBox1.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox1.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("T_JKR") = 0 Then
                CheckBox8.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox8.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("T_JPS") = 0 Then
                CheckBox9.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox9.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("T_BKSA") = 0 Then
                CheckBox10.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox10.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("T_JAS") = 0 Then
                CheckBox11.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox11.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("T_PERTANIAN") = 0 Then
                CheckBox12.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox12.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("T_MAJLIS") = 0 Then
                CheckBox13.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox13.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("T_JPBD") = 0 Then
                CheckBox14.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox14.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("T_KESIHATAN") = 0 Then
                CheckBox15.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox15.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("T_OTHERS") = 0 Then
                CheckBox16.Checked = False
                TextBox11.ResetText()
                TextBox11.Enabled = False
            Else
                CheckBox16.Checked = True
                TextBox11.Enabled = True
                TextBox11.Text = reader.GetString("T_OTHERS_TXT")
            End If
            '===========================DONE TECH DEPARTMENT====================
            If reader.GetInt32("PEJABAT_TANAH") = 0 Then
                CheckBox2.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox2.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("ULASAN_YB") = 0 Then
                CheckBox3.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox3.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("JKBB_APPROVED") = 0 Then
                CheckBox4.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox4.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("LAYOUT_ENDOSED") = 0 Then
                CheckBox5.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox5.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("5A_NOTICE") = 0 Then
                CheckBox6.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox6.Checked = True
            End If

            If reader.GetInt32("QT_ISSURANCE") = 0 Then
                CheckBox7.Checked = False
            Else
                CheckBox7.Checked = True
            End If
            '====================CHECKBOX DONE NOW IS THE TEXT=================
            TextBox12.Text = reader.GetString("TECH_DEPT_TXT")
            TextBox13.Text = reader.GetString("PEJABAT_TANAH_TXT")
            TextBox14.Text = reader.GetString("ULASAN_YB_TXT")
            TextBox15.Text = reader.GetString("JKBB_APPROVED_TXT")
            TextBox16.Text = reader.GetString("LAYOUT_ENDOSED_TXT")
            TextBox17.Text = reader.GetString("5A_NOTICE_TXT")
            TextBox18.Text = reader.GetString("QT_ISSURANCE_TXT")
            If reader.GetString("REMINDER_STATUS") Then
                RadioButton1.Checked = True
            Else
                RadioButton2.Checked = True
            End If
        End While
        reader.Dispose()
        sqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        If sqlConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            sqlConn.Close()
        End If
    Finally
        sqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**
I found the culprit by slowly stripping most of the codes. And the error was on this event.

```vb
Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton2.Checked Then
        Connect2Database()
        Try
            myCommand.CommandText = "Update kup_table SET REMINDER_STATUS = 0 Where ID = @theIDD"
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlConn.Close()
            MsgBox("The reminder has been switched off successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            sqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

I am not sure why it is giving a fatal error but when I commented this event out, it does not shows any fatal error anymore. If any of you know the answer please post one so I can mark thanks

Comment: it is probably related to using default form instances.  Cant see where `theId`  is declared, but `theID = New Integer = 0` is not doing what you think it is, I'm sort of surprised it compiles

Comment: @Plutonix Sorry for not being clear enough. theID is declared on top of the form as Dim theID as Integer

Comment: If the break point doesnt stop means ..?? Can you please try deleting .pdb - portable debugger and rebuilt the solution.

Comment: @goofyui I edited the question details to be more clear. Where can I find the pdb file? I cant seem to find it in the project folder

Comment: It should be projectname.pdb just like projectname.sln

Comment: @goofyui Deleted and rebuilt. Error is still showing. Tried restarting VS2015 as well

Comment: oh i never worked on VS 2015. Forget about the Error. Whether the break point is hitting.  Deleting the .pdb file helps you get into the break point. Now you have to use Quick Watch to see, what values you are getting in that line of code

Comment: @goofyui I switched the startup form to the Report form, when debug, the error shows up first before the form. This is really weird. No idea what is happening. And yesterday it was working fine.

Comment: Did you try to run this program outside the Visual Studio Environment? I mean launching the exe file directly as you were the final user. Do you get  the error?

Comment: @Steve I found where the culprit is. Check out the update above.

Comment: Please put the screen shot of your error ..

Comment: @goofyui The error just wrote the same in my question title. Was using mysqlException to print it out

Comment: In this line `myCommand.CommandText = "Update kup_table SET REMINDER_STATUS = 0 Where ID = @theIDD"`... where do you add parameter to your command, which correspond to `@theIDD`? On the side-note - whenever you add tags to your question, always add first, a language tag of the language in which your posted code is.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid question here. I found out why. This is because I have not parameterised the query yet before execution...

```
Private Sub RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton2.CheckedChanged
    If RadioButton2.Checked Then
        Connect2Database()
        Try
            myCommand.CommandText = "Update kup_table SET REMINDER_STATUS = 0 Where ID = @theIDD"
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlConn.Close()
            MsgBox("The reminder has been switched off successfully.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            sqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Really sorry and thanks so much for those that tried to help out. I missed out this ONE line.

```
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@theIDD", theID)
```

Comment: Ah, you already found the issue - I just posted comment about it